# Is there a time-zone issue?

Tags: support, comments

In the post ["How do I pass an expanded optional argument using expl3/xparse?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26486/how-do-i-pass-an-expanded-optional-argument-using-expl3-xparse) there are two comments at the bottom by Bruno and Joseph. surprisingly (to me at least) Joseph's answer is logged one hour after Bruno's question. How did this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a time issue.

Bruno wrote a comment to the answer before, and it has been deleted. I guess by himself. The reason could be that Joseph has fixed the problem mentioned by Bruno, so the comment has become obsolete. It's good to remove obsolete comments, also Joseph's comment regarding that it's fixed could be deleted now. Obsolete comments can be flagged.

Interesting: I flagged Josephs comment as obsolete, then it has been automatically deleted, obviously because a moderator set this flag.

Comment: ok, not a bad explanation :-). Getting rid of comments that no longer apply may be a good thing. I see you now removed the comment from Joseph as well. On the other hand you left one from Bruno which (I think) was also to an earlier revision of the same answer. At least I can't see to what it applies - which by the way is why I was so surprised about the order. after all Joseph wrote: "I fixed it in the answer" which gave me the impression that the two belonged together.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Yes, to my surprise it has been automatically deleted when I flagged it for Joseph's attention (see my updated answer). I put a comment there for Joseph, pointing to this question on meta, the additional comment will be removed later.